# MongoDB aggregation $lookup to a field that is an indexed array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying a fairly complex aggregate command on two collections involving `$lookup` pipeline. This normally works just fine on simple aggregation as long as index is set on `foreignField`.

But my `$lookup` is more complex as the indexed field is not just a normal `Int64` field but actually an array of `Int64`. When doing a simple `find()`, it is easy to verify using `explain()` that the index is being used. But explaining the aggregate pipeline does not explain whether index is being used in the `$lookup` pipeline. All my timing tests seem to indicate that the index is not being used. MongoDB version is 3.6.2. Db compatibility is set to 3.6.

As I said earlier, I am not using simple `foreignField` lookup but the 3.6-specific `pipeline` + `$match` + `$expr`...

Could using `pipeline` be showstopper for the index? Does anyone have any deep experience with the new `$lookup` pipeline syntax and/or the index on an array field?

**Examples**

Either of the following works fine and if explained, shows that index on `followers` is being used.

```
db.col1.find({followers: {$eq : 823778}})
db.col1.find({followers: {$in : [823778]}})
```

But the following one does not seem to make use of the index on `followers` [there are more steps in the pipeline, stripped for readability].

```
db.col2.aggregate([
    {$match:{field: "123"}},
    {$lookup:{
       from: "col1",
       let : {follower : "$follower"},
       pipeline: [{
            $match: {
                $expr: {
                    $or: [
                        { $eq : ["$follower", "$$follower"] },                       
                        { $in : ["$$follower", "$followers"]}
                       ]
                }                        
            }
        }],
       as: "followers_all"
     }
}])
```

Comment: did you find anything relevant ? I've found the [jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-31760) fixed in 3.7.1 ( dev version). Can you update and see if it works ? [This](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-32549) may be relavant as well.

Comment: Well, no. I ended up changing my db structure so that I don't have to use this complex lookup. I am very reluctant to use any sort of developer build on a production database. I guess I will have to wait for the next update cycle.

Comment: oh no. never meant to have you use dev build in prod. I was just wondering if you would verify and use the prod version when it is available.

Comment: I'd absolutely use it. But it is going to be a while before the next update. BTW, you seem to have given an answer to my question considering this is probably a bug or a missing feature. If you formulate it into an answer, I'd gladly mark it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a missing feature which is going to part of 3.8 version.

Currently eq matches in lookup sub pipeline are optimised to use indexes.
Refer [jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-31760) fixed in 3.7.1 ( dev version).

Also, [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-32549) may be relevant as well for non-multi key indexes.

Comment: Hi can you please provide a link to where it is stated that it will be part of 3.8? Cant seem to find any information on this improvement.

Comment: @medewit issue linked is  backported to 3.6 ( 3.6.3)  as well. So it should be available in the latest mongo version.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Im currently experiencing the same issue when using $gte in the lookup pipeline stage (vs just using $eq). Ive posted my (similar) question on the MongoDB mailing list.